# How do I install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel on Windows with ActiveState Perl?

Tags: perl, excel, module, cpan

I have installed Perl version 5.6.1. But it doesn't support [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Date::Calc). So I installed 5.10.0. Now I am writing a program that writes data in Excel using Perl. For this, I have to use [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) but [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) was not installed when I installed [ActiveState Perl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/).

So now do I have to install another version of perl or [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel) only?

If Spreadsheet::WriteExcel is enough, what exactly do I have to do?

Answer (score 11):

Your OS/distribution combination must have a way to fetch either precompiled or source packages. For example, on Windows with ActiveState Perl, you can use

```
C:\> ppm install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
```

You might also find the FAQ [What is CPAN?](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#What_is_CPAN) useful.

Comment: Thanks Sinan.
After execute this command, Its working fine.

Really I am sooooooooooooo happyyyyy....

Answer (score 3):

Spreadsheet::WriteExcel isn't part of the core perl distribution.  It is a module on [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org).  It will need to be installed separately. See the CPAN FAQ on [How to install perl modules](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_install_Perl_modules)

Answer (score 3):

You may have to [get the Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/INSTALL.html). The docs show you how to install in with ActivePerl.